# Luminosity distance from angular diameter distance

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, distance, gravitational-redshift, gravitational-lensing

Consider that I know the cosmological angular diameter distance at a given redshift :

$$D_{A}\left(z\right)=\frac{x_{object}}{\theta_{observer}}$$

Is there a general formula to compute the luminosity distance $D_{L}$ from $D_{A}$ without assuming an homogeneous cosmology ?

Comment: So are you interested in some sort of general integration over the different epochs of the universe with metric perturbations accounted for and not the simple $D_L=(1+z)^2D_A$?

Comment: @Jim I wonder whether the relation you point out is valid in a perturbed Universe.

Comment: Roughly speaking, it's about as valid as the unperturbed equations for $D_L$ and $D_A$ are individually. For $z<1$ these are great approximations. For $z>1$ they still hold and the data does follow the predictions, but perturbations have increasingly larger effects

Comment: @Jim Ok, I will rephrase the problem the other way. Consider a completely perturbed Universe in which I know, for a particular object: $x_{object}$ and $\theta_{observer}$ (I know them numerically, I do not have any expressions of them). Is there a way to compute $D_{L}$ from that ?

Comment: I don't know it off-hand. There is definitely a way; you should look around at some observational cosmology papers. Failing that method, the next step would be to re-derive the equations for $D_L$and $D_A$ only start with a perturbed metric. A majority of the math would be easy, but it would get really hairy right at the end.

Comment: But depending on your desired accuracy, you might want to just use the unperturbed approximation. The true result will be very close to that anyway.

Comment: I don't care whether it is close or not ... I want to know if it is true or not...

Comment: Looking for "Truth" is dangerous. Most of us are in the business of trying to find the best possible approximations to the real world. Beating a dead horse, but Newton was right (his gravity theory was "true"), but Einstein was more right (now GR is "true").

Answer (score 3):

The Etherington theorem states that the relation $$D_L=(1+z)^2D_A$$ remains valid for any space-time. The theorem shows the relation without using Einstein equations nor the matter content of the Universe. It only depends on photon conservation, and in the fact that photons travel through null geodesics in a Riemannian geometry.

Comment: The original paper is: I. M. H. Etherington (Philosophical Magazine ser. 7, vol. 15, 761 (1933))

Comment: This is **VERY** confusing if you consider the terminology and the intent of *Angular* Distance.  Luminosity is, by definition, line-of-sight.  Whereas *angular* is an arc across the sky.  I want to know what the difference is, in a flat universe, between Angular Distance $D_A$ and Comoving Distance $D_C$.  They seem to have the same formula and the same value.

Comment: @QuarkSoup: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measure#Overview, $D_A = D_M/(1+z)$ and $D_M = D_C$ in a flat universe.